# Compare two columns from separate sheets and return value from third column

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have two worksheets: Contacts and Payments.

**In the Contacts worksheet:**

Column A lists the ID (number) of each contact.

Column D has the first name of each contact.

**In the Payments worksheet:**

Column C lists the ID (number) of each contact who made a payment.

This worksheet doesn't include the person's first name, which is what I need. I need to see the first name of each contact who made a payment.

---

In Column A (new column) in Payments, I want to return the first name of the contact who made a payment.

Essentially, I need Column C in Payments to match Column A in Contacts and return the value of Column D in Contacts to Column A in Payments. Confusing.

Comment: VLOOKUP is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,A1)>0,VLOOKUP(A1,C:C,1),"")
```

Supposed, criteria in A1 and the lookup range is the whole column C.

EDIT: this should work instead of the above
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$D$1:$D$4,MATCH(Payments!C1,Contacts‌​!$A$1:$A$4,0)),"")`

Comment: Well, I have mistyped my answer, as well.

Comment: Well, I have mistyped my answer, as well, but this will work. Put it in D1 on Payments worksheet, if the first ID to lookup is in C1. Otherwise, modify criteria. `=IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$D$1:$D$4,MATCH(Payments!C1,Contacts!$A$1:$A$4,0)),"")`